# c# excel 2007 automation - how to follow no two dot rule while looping?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007

I'm using code lines similar to the one below several times throughout the loop. It works all fine EXCEPT it doesn't follow the "no two dot rule", right?

```
wksheet.Cells(cell.Row, "J").Value
```

I can store cell.Row as an int, but where to go from there? Is there a function that lets me pass row number and column letter and get the value of that particular cell while still following the rule?

It would be a pain to declare and then set the range variable every time I want to get a particular cell's value inside the loop.

[How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp)

^this link explains no two dot rule.

Comment: What's the "no two dot rule"?

Comment: @RB Trying not to acquire unintended com references that you then can't clean up with Marshal.ReleaseComObject. Alliterated to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: I guess this must be it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: @TPR can you show your loop please? Note that wksheet.Cells(int, int) is a range itself, so you first assign that to a variable, then you take it's value, then you Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could break it down

```
var row = cell.Row;
var cell = wksheet.Cells(row, "J");
var value = cell.Value;
```

Comment: that's what I mean, it's such a pain to have these two-three lines going around anytime I want to get a simple cell value. I guess I got to do what I got to do.

Comment: @TPR if you are doing this a lot I guess you could right a function that takes a worksheet, row and column and returns a value.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.